# How to multiple substitution with sed on OSX

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

im trying to do this on an OSx Terminal

```
 sed -i -e 's/something/somethingelse/g' \
 -e 's/someotherthing/someothertingagain/g' \
 -e 's/multised/isfun/g' \
 file.txt
```

this works fine on Linux, but not on OSX. Is there a way to do this with sed on OSX, or do I have to use something else? Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

[OSX sed](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) does not work with empty extension, to override orginal file use `sed -i ''`.

```
sed -i '' -e 's/something/somethingelse/g;s/someotherthing/someothertingagain/g;s/multised/isfun/g' file.txt
```